# Export a list definition to text file or script?

Tags: list, powershell

Is there any reasonable way to export a list definition to a text file or script so it can be used to create a new list after some tweaks to the column names, and the addition of some additional columns? I specifically am not interested in "Save list as template", and am more interested in something which can be used via Powershell. I would love it if there was something similar to a SQL "CREATE TABLE" statement at our disposal.

My use case is, I have an existing list with about 40 columns in it. This list will be used as a pre-populator in a form where a user will fill in desired changes, along with additional columns, which will be submitted to a new list based on the source list. This is in a SP2010 Server environment.

For the dual reasons of accuracy and laziness, I wish to avoid having to hand-create those 40 columns.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing I can come up with is simply using a content type. You gain the flexibility of modifying lists post-creation by updating the content type definition and you can add/remove columns at your leisure in the destination list. Building a list with a content type in powershell is a cakewalk and you minimize any scripting/development complications.

You can re-use the list definition's schema xml for your content type by exporting it

http://get-spscripts.com/2011/01/export-and-importcreate-site-columns-in.html

```
$sourceWeb = Get-SPWeb http://portal
$xmlFilePath = "C:\Install\Script-SiteColumns.xml"

#Create Export Files
New-Item $xmlFilePath -type file -force

#Export Site Columns to XML file
Add-Content $xmlFilePath "<?xml version=`"1.0`" encoding=`"utf-8`"?>"
Add-Content $xmlFilePath "`n<Fields>"
$sourceWeb.Fields | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Group -eq "Custom Columns") {
        Add-Content $xmlFilePath $_.SchemaXml
    }
}
Add-Content $xmlFilePath "</Fields>"

$sourceWeb.Dispose()
```

Personally, I'd advise carefully recreating these fields manually for optimization purposes if you're planning on using those fields for a very long time.